# How to inherit from a QT form in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have created a QT form in a previous project (let's call it project 1) in Visual Studio, and now another project has almost the same UI properties and design as the previous project, hence I am thinking of creating a QT form project in Visual Studio (project 2), and inheriting from the previous QT form instead of rewriting the code. example, for project 1 :

```
class GUIBase : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GUIBase (QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~GUIBase ();

public slots:
    //some slot definitions
};
```

And in Project 2, the derived form:

```
class GUIDerived: public GUIBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GUIDerived (QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~GUIDerived ();
};
```

When compiling project 2, it has a problem when moc-ing GUIBase in Project 1(because the header file for GUIBase is in a different folder). So my main question is, how do I set up the moc process? Do I just moc GUIBase or do I need to moc both GUIBase and GUIDerived? And do I still need a .ui file for GUIDerived?

Sorry if the question is not too clear, it's because I am not too entirely sure of the process myself.

Comment: if you want to copy the UI to an other project, you can reuse the .ui file, include it to the project the same way you did it in the first project. the MainWindow class ist just a container for the UI, the layout and controls of the UI are stored in the .ui file. if you want to reuse methods you wrote in the GUIBase, you need to copy the GUIBase header and cpp file and also the .ui file in the new project

Comment: thanks for the comment. I thought of that as well, but I'm trying to see if there's a possibility to put the base files in a central location, and use them from there. I will need to develop 2 more projects using the same ui design and format.

Answer (score 0):

make a library project (.dll) and put the UI in it (.ui file and sourcecode for the UI). use the library in all projects you need it.

Library (header):

```
#ifndef GUI_BASE_H
#define GUI_BASE_H

#ifdef UILIB
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLL GUIBase : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GUIBase (QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~GUIBase ();

public slots:
    //some slot definitions
};

#endif //GUI_BASE_H
```

preprocessor define in lib project:

```
UILIB
```

the lib header file and resulting .lib file must be available in all projects. add the .lib file to the "Additional Dependencies" in the Linker/Input section of the Project Properties in Visual Studio (and be sure VS knows the path to the lib, you can add a lib path in the linker/general/"Additional Library Directories" section)